# jQuery TimeCircles event listeners scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, scope, addeventlistener

I'm testing out the jquery timer **"TimeCircles"** from [here](https://github.com/wimbarelds/TimeCircles) and I've been able to produce a minute / second timer for *30 min* with an alert warning at *25 min*, I'm trying to add a threshold event at *20 min* that would change the colours of the circles.

I'm not entirely sure how to access the `TimeCircles()` properties after it's been instantiated.  We instantiate like so:

```
$('#idle_timer').attr('data-timer',1800);
$('#idle_timer').TimeCircles({ time: { 
    Days: { show:false }, 
    Hours: { show:false }, 
    Minutes: { color: '#4D8DC1' }, 
    Seconds: { color: '#4D8DC1' } } })
  .addListener(
    function(unit,value,total) { 
        if (total == 1200) {  

            // CHANGE COLOUR OF TimeCircles HERE

        } else if (total == 1500) { 
            alert('Your session will expire in 5 minutes, you should save your work and / or reload the page.'); 
        } 
    } 
  );
```

In the test for `"total == 1200"`, how could I access the minutes / seconds colour attributes so for instance both could be changed to red? `$(this)` doesn't seem to be available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find a solution with the original developer. Part of the problem was that .data() attributes set dynamically weren't considered in his code, that's been updated. From there it was easy, just add a listener, and then within it test for a `total` value and then just instantiate a new instance which overwrites the original...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var idle_timer = $('div#idle_timer',window.parent.document);
idle_timer.data('timer',15);
idle_timer.TimeCircles({ time: { Days: { show:false }, Hours: { show:false }, Minutes: { color: '#4D8DC1' }, Seconds: { color: '#4D8DC1' } } })
.addListener(
    function(unit,value,total) { 
        if (total == 10) { 
            idle_timer.data('timer',10);
            idle_timer.TimeCircles({ time: { Days: { show:false }, Hours: { show:false }, Minutes: { color: '#900' }, Seconds: { color: '#900' } } })
        } else if (total == 5) { 
            alert('Your session will expire in 5 seconds, you should save your work and / or reload the page.');
        } 
    } 
);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is ideal, but works:

```
$('#idle_timer').data('TimeCircles_config', { time: { 
    Days: { show:false }, 
    Hours: { show:false }, 
    Minutes: { color: '#4D8DC1' }, 
    Seconds: { color: '#4D8DC1' } } }
);

$('#idle_timer').TimeCircles($('#idle_timer').data('TimeCircles_config'))
  .addListener(
    function(unit,value,total) { 
        if (total == 1200) {  
            var config = $(this).data('TimeCircles_config'); //If thid doesn't work, use $('#idle_timer').data(...)
            var minColor = config.Minutes.color;

            // CHANGE COLOUR OF TimeCircles HERE

        } else if (total == 1500) { 
            alert('Your session will expire in 5 minutes, you should save your work and / or reload the page.'); 
        } 
    } 
  );
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately $(this) isn't available in the listener, which is another issue and I've raised this on GitHub, but the other is that I don't believe that TimeCircles() is affected by a change to the config array after it's been instantiated, from the sounds of it, it may need to be destroyed and recreated with the same time left and the new colour array.  Couldn't get this to do anything for me in JSfiddle either, do you have a working test running?

Comment: I've worked with the developer to update his code and we've found a different solution, see my answer.  Thanks for your help.